# JsLink Sharepoint Change standard item view list to side by side

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, list-view, jslink, list-item

I want to change the Standard Sharepoint view List from standard view :
Item1 
Item2 
Item3 
[image]

To Side By Side Items : 
Item1  Item2  Item3 
My JS :

```
(function () { 

        var priorityFiledContext = {}; 
        priorityFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
        priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
            "LinkFilename": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate }           
        };          
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext); 

    })(); 

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) { 
    var results= "";
    var FullName = ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef;     
    Results = "<a title='Folder' <img src='/Style%20Library/icons/folder.png'></a><div title="+FullName+" style='text-align: center'>"+FullName+"</div>";  
    return Results;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here just a simple template for your reference:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
            Templates: {                
                Body: function (ctx, field, listItem, listSchema) {
                    var data = ctx.ListData.Row;
                    //the logic how you render your data.                    
                    var tmprow = "<div style='float:left;margin:20px 10px 20px 20px'>{0}</div>";
                    var row="";
                    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //replace with your default folder render format
                        var OOBRender = "<a class='ms-listlink' onmousedown='javascript:VerifyFolderHref(this,event,'','FALSE','1','','','');return false;' onclick='return HandleFolder(this,event,'/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FShared%20Documents%2F{0}&amp;FolderCTID=0x0120005E9B0D4B8E07CF489B29BEB10374CED0&amp;View=%7B57E22E8F%2D35FD%2D4E5E%2DBAFE%2D7084F8036667%7D','TRUE','FALSE','','FALSE','1','','','','','1','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff');' onfocus='OnLink(this)' href='/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2FShared%20Documents%2F{1}&amp;FolderCTID=0x0120005E9B0D4B8E07CF489B29BEB10374CED0&amp;View=%7B57E22E8F%2D35FD%2D4E5E%2DBAFE%2D7084F8036667%7D'>{2}</a>";

                        row += tmprow.replace("{0}", OOBRender.replace("{0}", data[i].FileLeafRef).replace("{1}", data[i].FileLeafRef).replace("{2}", data[i].FileLeafRef));
                    }
                    return "<table><tr><td>" + row + "</td></tr></table>";
                },                
            }
        });        
    </script>
```

[image]